# Hosts not recognized?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, hosts

Basically, nobody can establish a connection to anything I host. The website, teamspeak, and game servers. I think it may have something to do with the hosts file or network configuration, but I have tried most things to no avail.

I am running CentOS 6.2 64bit

Edit: I am able to ssh into the server, and I can ping localhost/visit the website through local host, but not through remote connections from another computer. I don't believe it's a firewall because I have never had a firewall running.

Here is a link to relevant information: http://pastebin.com/xRUcr9jE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, are you running this from home? Big chance is that if you are your ISP does not allow certain connections or has a firewall installed in your router.

EDIT:

Check your iptables

Comment: I am not running it from home. I host small competitive doom servers from a VPS. I do not recall ever installing a firewall, so I think we can rule that out.

Comment: I am very sorry for the stupid question guys. Turns out I had forgotten to flush some IPTables rules I made ages ago. They were dropping connections to my server. Very sorry! Thank you Lucas for making me double-check!

Comment: Actually you can't CentOS comes standard with a firewall called iptables, you might want to issue this command as root: iptables --list